# Step name already exists error when using dataflow runner

Tags: go, apache-beam

Cross-posting from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kythe/86kNuSCeorI, since I was directed here by Beam faq for Beam questions.

In short, I run a job written using the `golang` sdk successfully using the `direct` runner, but trying to use the `dataflow` runner I get the following error in the google cloud console:

> 2019-02-17 (12:03:53) Step with name e19 already exists. Duplicates
>   are not allowed.

I attach the plan that was printed to the stderr at https://pastebin.com/vpu3U52j. Grepping for e19: https://pastebin.com/L24L1guT.

I'm not very familiar with beam yet. I wonder which part is responsible for generating the step names? What are likely causes of a collision?

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to be https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5381 based on list feedback.

Comment: In Java, you have a parameter for a step name in `apply` function. for example:  `.apply("build-table-row",TableRowBuilder.of(....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug actually, sent PR to beam.